# Why does changing the Resolution Divisions parameter in Mantaflow change the scale of the simulation?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

My understanding of Resolution Divisions is that it should affect the accuracy/voxel size of the simulation. Therefore a typical workflow would be to start with a lower number of divisions to get the look you are after, then increase the Resolution Divisions for the final bake to get better quality.

However, when I increase the Resolution Divisions my liquid simulation gets dramatically smaller, and the way it interacts with Force Fields etc is very different. The end result is that my final bake looks nothing like the results I'm getting at lower divisions.

Is this expected? And if so, is there a workflow that allows for quick baking to get the simulation looking right that can then be baked at a higher quality for the final render?